# How to set the label of a layout programmatically?

Tags: android

Is it possible to set a label of a class/screen/layout programmatically? I am retrieving a short string e.g. "Today is Sunday" from a webpage and I would like to set that string as the title/label of the screen.

What I meant for label/title: The grey box at the top of the screen which can be set manually in the manifest file.

[image: label]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `setTitle(int titleId)` method

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle%28int%29